# Join tables from multiple databases

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a legacy web application, WAR packaging.

It is written with hardcoded sql strings in DAO files. It connects to multiple schemas of an oracle db.

```
select ... from schema1.one_table join schema2.other_table on...
```

What I have to achieve is to make this work with schemas in separate databases.

I was advised to autowire two jdbcTemplates and query the data from them, then do the joining-filtering logic in java.

I smell this is a bad solution, for several reasons. I don't want to implement joining-filtering in java, I am sure the oracle engine does it hundred times more efficiently.

How can I rewrite queries to specify not only the schema but the db instance also? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think this cannot be done directly with JDBC. you can follow below steps as I did in one of my projects:

- Create a dblink between databases with the help of DBA.
- Create synonym of remote database tables in your primary database.

This way you can access remote tables directly from one database and you can then use any of plain JDBC/JDBCTemplate/Hibernate etc to run your business.

Comment: Just a quick comment, a performance can be far different (worse) when using database links.

Comment: @ibre5041 Sure, but it will likely perform the same or better than the solution described by the OP.

Comment: @ibre5041: but DBLinks are the only solution to do cross-database queries in Oracle